# how to add new column to Big-calendar to display details of each event?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want a column which displays details of each event
and I also want to display only one event in each line
(if there is more than one event in the same line they should be displayed separately)

I added a separated column but its not aligned with events of calendar